# Opengl glLoadIdentity() faster than glPushMatrix()/glPopMatrix()?

Tags: performance, opengl

I make a particle emitter. I do not need to manage a parent / child hierachy in my transformations.

What is the fastest?

```
glPushMatrix()
    ..apply tranformations
    ...draw object
glPopMatrix()
```

or

```
glLoadIdentity()
    ..apply tranformations
    ...draw object
```

for each my particules ?

I tried both techniques in my program but I do not see any difference in the FPS. The few variations can come from a other programs on my PC, such as anti-virus. (I guess)

Comment: These do different things, for what it's worth. Loading the identity without push/pop means that you're not really tracking nested state. Maybe it's OK for what you're doing, but you'd generally want to push, load identity, then pop when done with that sequence.

Answer (score 5):

Neither. If you're rendering a particle system where the number of particles could ever be a performance issue, sending a transform for *each particle* (which means issuing a separate rendering call for each particle) will kill any hope of performance.

If you want a particle system, your best bet is to put the particles all in an array ([preferably a buffer object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming)) and render it in one single call.

Comment: +1 and clarify for OP that it's not the transform *per se* for each particle, it's issuing a separate draw call for each one that kills you.

Comment: This is a very interesting answer. (I do not accept your answer for now because it does not answer the question of the topic. But that answer to my problem.) Thank you.

Comment: (though I don't think you can use the buffer object if you want to display the particles sorted by the distance from the camera. The order will change constantly.)

Comment: @mrstack: So will their position and orientation. How is order any different? You're talking about buffer streaming either way.

Comment: @mrstack: Theoretically `glLoadIdentity` can be faster or slower than `glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix` depending on how it's implemented. Practically it makes no measureable difference, because operations like those are not executed immediately, but queued up into a long state transistion vector that get's applied to the rasterizer only just before when it actually matters.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that `glPush/glPop` is a different thing that `glIdentity`

`glPush` saves the current top of the matrix stack and `glPop` restores that state.

`glIdentity` clears the current top of the matrix stack.

There are several issues with your design:

- this functionality is deprecated in modern OpenGL so it is better to use something else for the matrix stuff. For instance GLM
- If you do that for every particle it will be a huge performance bottlenect for the application!

For particle update/rendering it is better to:

- calculate final/world position of particles in a loop and save those positions to the buffer, use VBO for instance
- use the previous buffer to render points. That way you can use one draw call (+ several lines of the setup) to draw huge number of points.

here is a nice link about that: http://3dgep.com/?p=1057